# how to extract the string pattern without duplicate using grep

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, grep, sh

I am using this grep command to extract the strings

```
grep -Enro --exclude=\*features.cc --exclude=\*.h --exclude=\*switches.cc '\bk[A-Z]\w*' ./*
```

my output is:-

> ./vulkan/generate_bindings.py:409:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/generate_bindings.py:588:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/generate_bindings.py:603:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:24:kSkippedErrors
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:39:kSkippedErrors
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:89:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:95:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:291:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:292:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_surface.cc:27:kPreferredVkFormats
> ./vulkan/vulkan_surface.cc:32:kPreferredVkFormats
> ./vulkan/vulkan_surface.cc:79:kMinImageCount
> skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:324:kVertex_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:327:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:332:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:339:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:343:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:348:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:354:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:361:kStencil_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:364:kPixelStore_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:368:kPixelStore_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:371:kProgram_GrGLBackendState
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:374:kProgram_GrGLBackendState

But there are duplicates in the output. The same string is repeating. I want to extract unique strings. could someone guide me through this? thanks in advance.

I need the output as below:

> ./vulkan/generate_bindings.py:409:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:24:kSkippedErrors
> ./vulkan/vulkan_instance.cc:89:kVulkanRequiredApiVersion
> ./vulkan/vulkan_surface.cc:27:kPreferredVkFormats
> ./vulkan/vulkan_surface.cc:79:kMinImageCount
> ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:324:kVertex_GrGLBackendState ./skia_bindings/gles2_implementation_with_grcontext_support.cc:339:kStencil_GrGLBackendState

I don't the same string to be repeated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do provide more clear details on your expected output in your question that will make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: This might help: [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do you want the output unique per file or unique regardless the file name?

Comment: hey, I am sorry. I have edited my question. I want a unique string regardless of the file name. I mean, if a file has two or more unique strings it should extract.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand, but isn't `grep xxxxx xxxxxx | uniq` what you are looking for?

Comment: it is not working. Still gives me the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` has a `-m` switch, meaning that you can limit the maximum amount of matches. Using `-m 1` should solve your problem, so you would get something like:

```
grep -Enro -m 1 --exclude=\*features.cc --exclude=\*.h --exclude=\*switches.cc '\bk[A-Z]\w*' ./*
```

Comment: While this is a useful switch, it'll remove unique matches coming from the same file. I think it's not a proper solution.

Comment: This is the way I understood the question. Let's await the response from the author.

Comment: yeah, it is removing the unique matches from the same file. But I need to extract unique strings, whether it is from the same file or a different one.